# File size and storage limits on GitHub

Tags: github

From an answer given at [Is there a limit in the number of GitHub organizations a single account can create?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37545/is-there-a-limit-in-the-number-of-github-organizations-a-single-account-can-crea/37560), it seems that

> if you don't see a hard limit published, you'll have to consider the main guideline of "be reasonable".

Also some searching has found that at https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota

> For best performance, we recommend repositories be kept under 1GB each. This limit is easy to stay within if large files (typically, binaries) are kept out of the repository. If your repository exceeds 1GB, you might receive a polite email from support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository to bring it back down under 1GB.

Is my understanding correct that this is a per-repo limit? For example, can I have 2 0.5 GB repositories? Will a single .99 GB file affect this performance or 99 .1GB files?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768454/what-is-the-repository-limit-for-github-com

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### GitHub storage limits as of Sep 2015

Per repository git file: **100 MB** (strict)

> GitHub will warn you when pushing files larger than 50 MB. You will not be allowed to push files larger than 100 MB.
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/#conditions-for-large-files

Per repository: **~1 GB** (recommended)

> We recommend repositories be kept under 1GB each. This limit is easy to stay within if large files are kept out of the repository. If your repository exceeds 1GB, you might receive a polite email from GitHub Support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository to bring it back down.
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/#file-and-repository-size-limitations

Per repository binary [release file](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/): **2 GB** (strict)

> We don't limit the total size of your binary release files, nor the bandwidth used to deliver them. However, each individual file must be under 2GB in size.
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/distributing-large-binaries/

Per account: **No limit**

> GitHub doesn't have any set disk quotas. We try to provide abundant storage for all Git repositories, within reason.
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/#content-wrapper

#### GitHub large file support (filesize >100 MB)

GitHub supports [large file storage](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-large-file-storage/) for all Git repositories with [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com) — a new, open-source Git extension.

An outline for the development, originally called GitHub Asset Management System, a large file asset management system for GitHub:

- 22 Sep 2013 -- [committed](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/commit/d8f780329b64e789553bc8ccccfb993ebc430325) to GitHub.
- 08 Apr 2015 -- Large file support for GitHub was [announced](https://github.com/blog/1986-announcing-git-large-file-storage-lfs) and [early access](https://github.com/early_access/git-lfs) made available.
- 01 Oct 2015 -- git-lfs is [released to all accounts](https://github.com/blog/2069-git-large-file-storage-v1-0), large files are supported for free up to 1 GB per account and a monthly bandwidth quota of 1 GB. Higher quotas are available for [purchase](https://github.com/blog/1986-announcing-git-large-file-storage-lfs#pricing).

#### GitHub bandwidth limits

Repository git files bandwidth limit: **not significantly greater than average GitHub user**

> If your bandwidth usage significantly exceeds the average bandwidth usage (as determined solely by GitHub) of other GitHub customers, we reserve the right to immediately disable your account or throttle your file hosting until you can reduce your bandwidth consumption.
>
> [GitHub Terms of Service section G item 12](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/#g-general-conditions)

Repository binary [release files](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/) bandwidth limit: **No limit**

> We don't limit the total size of your binary release files, nor the bandwidth used to deliver them. However, each individual file must be under 2GB in size.
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/distributing-large-binaries/

Comment: For "GitHub bandwidth limits" as of October 2020, see https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/site-policy/github-acceptable-use-policies#7-excessive-bandwidth-use

Answer (score -2):

github seems to have added a limit of 1000 files per directory.